# How to obtain multiple commands in antlr4?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I'm developing a shell implementation in Java and I'm using antlr4 to parse the grammar. I would like to parse the input commands one by one and store them in an arraylist where I will execute the commands later.

For example, an input of "echo hello; echo world" should return an arraylist of two Call objects. If it helps, a Call object represents a simple command.

However, the return value of the visitChildren method is being overwritten by the latest parsed command. How can I parse one command, add it to my arraylist, then continue parsing the next command and so on?

**CommandConverter.java**

```
package parse;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import app.ApplicationFactory;
import shell.ShellGrammarBaseVisitor;
import shell.ShellGrammarParser;

public class CommandConverter extends ShellGrammarBaseVisitor<Command> {
    
    ApplicationFactory appFactory = new ApplicationFactory();

    @Override
    public Command visitCommands(ShellGrammarParser.CommandsContext ctx) {
        //ArrayList<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        return visitChildren(ctx);
    }
    @Override
    public Command visitAtomicCommand(ShellGrammarParser.AtomicCommandContext ctx) {
        int childCount = ctx.getChildCount();
        String appName = ctx.getChild(0).getText();
        ArrayList<String> appArgs = new ArrayList<>();
        if(childCount > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
                appArgs.add(ctx.getChild(i).getText());
            }
        }
        return new Call(appFactory.getApplication(appName), appArgs);
    }
}
```

**ShellGrammar.g4 (partially)**

```
grammar ShellGrammar;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

commands : atomicCommand (';' atomicCommand )*

atomicCommand : NONSPECIAL (value)*;

value : (NONSPECIAL | DOUBLEQUOTED | SINGLEQUOTED);

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
NONSPECIAL : ~['";\r\n\t ]+;
DOUBLEQUOTED : '"' (~'"')* '"';
SINGLEQUOTED : '\'' (~'\'')* '\'';

WHITESPACE : [\r\n\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read it out loud, this definition, doesn't make much sense:

```java
public Command visitCommands(ShellGrammarParser.CommandsContext ctx) {
```

You're visiting `commands` but expect a `Command` in return??

In this simple case, it's probably best to remember that a Visitor doesn't need to handle visiting *EVERY* Context type (it's rather rare that that works for a full grammar, as finding a common return type applicable for all nodes proves to be difficult).  You can just override the methods for Context types you actually intend to visit.

In your case, `commands` is you "top-level" rule, so the parse tree node you get back from your parse (using the `parser.commands();` call) will be a `CommandsContext`

you could do something akin to:  (where `pt` is the node you got back from the parse.)

```java
  for (AtomicCommandContext child : pt.children) {
   // handle the child command
   // could be adding it to a list
   // could be just processing the command 
  }
```

The benefit of commands is that you're in charge of calling the visitor for each child.  `visitChildren` is just a convenience methods that iterates through all the children calling the visitor for you.

There are methods in the `Visitor` class that you can override if you want to make your visitor return a `List<Command>` from calling `visitChildren()`, but the code above is probably simplest for what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, I should say that Command is an interface and I have a few classes that implement it, eg Call, Pipe and Seq. Seq is going to hold an ArrayList of Commands.

Comment: I've just tried iterating through all the children of the node and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!